# How to Disable all BizTalk Hostinstances with PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, biztalk

I'm trying to make a PowerShell script to stop and disable from starting all BizTalk host instances.

Stopping is no problem with this code:

```
$hosts = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer'
foreach($hostinst in $hosts) {
    if ( ($hostinst.ServiceState -ne 1) -and ($hostinst.ServiceState -ne 8) ) {
        Write-Host "Stop Hostinstance" $hostinst.HostName
        $hostinst.Stop()
        Write-Host "Hostinstance" $hostinst.HostName "stopped"
    }
}
```

But now I'm trying to Disable all stopped Host Instances from starting up.

My first try gives no error but doesn't do anything.
All host instance are mentioned in the output but they are not disabled.

```
$hosts = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer'
foreach($hostinst in $hosts) {
    if ( ($hostinst.ServiceState -eq 1) -or ($hostinst.ServiceState -eq 8) ) {
        Write-Host "disable Hostinstance" $hostinst.HostName
        $hostinst.IsDisabled = $true
        Write-Host "Hostinstance" $hostinst.HostName "is disabled"
    }
}
```

My second try gives an error because of the -path parameter.

```
$hosts = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer'
foreach($hostinst in $hosts) {
    if ( ($hostinst.ServiceState -eq 1) -or ($hostinst.ServiceState -eq 8) ) {
        Write-Host "disable Hostinstance" $hostinst.HostName
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $hostinst__PATH -Name IsDisabled -Value $True
        # $hostinst.IsDisabled = $true
        Write-Host "Hostinstance" $hostinst.HostName "is disabled"
    }
}
```

What is the correct method to set the property `IsDisabled` to `$true` or to `$false`?

Answer (score 1):

BizTalk host instance is a windows service. So you can use powershell's  Get-Service cmdlet to stop and disable it.

Suppose your host name is BizTalkServerApplication

Then following script will do the job:

```
Get-Service -Name BTSSvc`$BizTalkServerApplication  | Stop-Service -PassThru | Set-Service -StartupType disabled
```

Also note the "$" is escaped as "`$"

Answer (score 1):

@Zee is close, but still needs to loop through..  Here's one way to do that - concat the host's name with BTSSvc

```
$hosts = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer'


foreach($hostinst in $hosts) {
    if ( ($hostinst.ServiceState -ne 8) ) { # ignore isolated hosts

        $svcName = ('BTSSvc${0}' -f $hostinst.HostName) # get something Get-Service can work with

        Get-Service -Name $svcName | Stop-Service -PassThru | Set-Service -StartupType disabled        
        Write-Host "Hostinstance" $hostinst.HostName "stopped and disabled"
    }
}
```

And if you need to set them back to Automatic/started:

```
$hosts = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer'


foreach($hostinst in $hosts) {
    if ( ($hostinst.ServiceState -ne 8) ) { # ignore isolated hosts

        $svcName = ('BTSSvc${0}' -f $hostinst.HostName) # get something Get-Service can work with

        Get-Service -Name $svcName | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic -PassThru | Start-Service
        Write-Host "Hostinstance" $hostinst.HostName "stopped and disabled"
    }
}
```

And here's a way that might be even a little clearer:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name.StartsWith("BTSSvc") } | Stop-Service -PassThru | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers.
However there are 2 reasons why this doesn't work completely fine in a BizTalk environment with multiple servers.
First in your solution you have to manually configure the list of servers for each environment in OTAP. With the option Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace 'root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer' BizTalk knows which servers belong the BizTalkGroup.

Second (and more important) the present state is "Automatic(Delayed start)".
Setting the state back to Automatic(Delayed start) with Powershell script is not posible according to several websites.

I understand now why $hostinst.IsDisabled = $true didn't work.
Because the change must be saved first.
That's why I have added  a command to save the changes.
$script:btscatalog.SaveChanges() | Out-Null

Unfortunately still nothing seems to be changed.

Comment: Frank:  Have you tried the method in this blog: http://metah.ch/blog/2012/09/how-to-change-a-service-startup-type-with-powershell/  ?   It need access the registry. and since you are working on multi server environment, you need access all these servers' registry remotely. But it is still can be done,

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I wil try this option.

Answer (score 0):

Do ***not*** use default windows service to disable the BizTalk service

Use WMI to get list of BizTalk host instances

```
$inProcessHosts = "HostType=1"
$nsBTS = "root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer"
$filter = "($inProcessHosts)"     
$hostInstances = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_HostInstance -Namespace $nsBTS -Filter $filter
```

Disable items in a for each loop (redirect output from put)

```
foreach ($hostInstance in $hostinstances)
{
    $hostInstance.IsDisabled = $true
    $hostInstance.Put() > $null
}
```

EDIT:
There is a way to set automatic (delayed start) if needed

```
#=== Change the startup type for BizTalk services to Automatic (Delayed Start) ===#
get-service BTSSvc* | foreach-object -process { SC.EXE config $_.Name start= delayed-auto}
```

From Technet WIKI:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19701.biztalk-server-best-practices-create-and-configure-biztalk-server-host-and-host-instances.aspx